# boleanos con condiciones en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

hola tengo la duda como puedo crear una columna de boleanos con condiciones en Python por ejemplo quisiera solamente que cuando sea True en la columna 1 y true en la columna 2 de un dataframe , me vote true y lo demás sean false en otra columna

hice con logical pero al parecer no funciona. Espero que me ayuden porfavor

Comment: Hola, ARK2, mencionas "columna" pero no la estructura de datos... ¿list, numpy.array, pandas.DataFrame, etc? Considera agregar un [mcve] y el código intentado para que la pregunta sea más clara y adecuada para el sitio.

Comment: es un dataframe de dos columnas de boleanos , la idea es que cuando los dos sean True , me salga True , si no es asi entonces que salgan falsos las otras condiciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Eso no es un AND? `df['col3'] = df['col1']&df['col2']`

El siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd

d={'col1':[True, True, False, False], 'col2':[True, False, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col3'] = df['col1']&df['col2']
```

nos entrega:

```
>>> df
       col1    col2    col3
0      True    True    True
1      True   False   False
2     False    True   False
3     False   False   False
```

Comment: excelente, ya lo habia resuelto como un tipo de concatenacion de palabras,pero también tu solución es buena .Muchas gracias !